# Infinite summation of a trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

$\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\sin(\frac{n\pi y}{L})\surd(k^2+\frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2})$

I am trying to solve the above summation. I still could not figure out if this summation converges or diverges due to the term $\surd(k^2+\frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2})$. Is there any method to formally calculate this type of summations?

Comment: Where did this series come from? It looks a lot like a fourier series, but I can't tell what function would give those coefficients.

Comment: @AlexZorn I derived it from a Quanum mechanics theory, molecule interaction in a cavity like structure (original expression has some other terms also). Here $n$ is a integer which gives the mode number. $L$ is the cavity length and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So long as $\frac{x}{L}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ nor $\frac{x}{L}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ nor ${\frac{x}{L} \in \mathbb{Z}  \wedge  x=y+zL}$, where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ then the series will diverge. I know this because there will exist an $N$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L}\right)$$ (i.e., that the sum is periodic), whilst the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\sqrt{k^2+\frac{n^2{\pi}^2}{L^2}}>0$ for all $n>0$. Hence if we re-express our series as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ then for all $n$ there exists an $m>n$ such that $a_m>a_n$, which implies the series diverges.

Comment: Thanks I got your point. However I didn't get what you meant by   $x=y\pm 1$. What if that is not the case, will the summation converge?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be $\frac{x}{L}\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge x=y+zL $ where $z\in\mathbb{Z}$. The point is that we don't need both $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{n \pi y}{L}\right)$ to be identically zero for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but rather that their products be identically zero.

Comment: it makes sense. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. Welcome to MSE!